# How to read 1st column from csv and separate into multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to separate a column that I read from a .csv file into a multidimensional array. So, if the first column is read into a single array and looks like this:

```
t = ['90-0066', '24', '33', '34', '91-0495', '22', '33', '92-6676', '23', '32']
```

How do I write the code in python for every value like '90-0066' the following numbers are put into an array until the next - value? So I would like the array to look like:

```
t = [['24', '33', '34'], ['22', '33'], ['23', '32']]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` in a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
t = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(t, key=str.isdigit) if k]
```

`t` becomes:

```
[['24', '33', '34'], ['22', '33'], ['23', '32']]
```

If the numbers are possibly floating points, you can use regex instead:

```
import re
t = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(t, key=lambda s: bool(re.match(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?$', s)) if k]
```

Comment: Do you know how I would write that if the numbers were float instead? Say instead, I had ['90-0066', '24.0', '33.0', '34.0', '91-0495', '22.0', '33.0', '92-6676', '23.0', '32.0']?

Answer (score 1):

Or `zip` longest with two list comprehensions:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> l=[i for i,v in enumerate(t) if not v.isdigit()]
>>> [t[x+1:y] for x,y in zip_longest(l,l[1:])]
[['24', '33', '34'], ['22', '33'], ['23', '32']]
>>>
```